# What is wrong with my JAX-RS configuration?

Tags: java, rest, maven, jax-rs, wildfly

SOLVED: The problem was something related to my context name, it was defined as "Application" but my browser was opening with "application", and this capital A was the key to solve the issue.

Can anyone please help me with this? I can't get JAX-RS to work, I am using WildFly 8.1.0.Final and I've set my project up using JBoss Forge 2
Take a loot at my files by now, as I did not get any console error

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

RestApplication.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(TestEndpoint.class));
    }
}
```

TestEndpoint.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/test")
public class TestEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getString() {
        return "worked";
    }

}
```

I tried to access it by

```
http://localhost:8080/application/api/test
```

but I got a 404 error page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try @ApplicationPath("/")

Comment: Did you override the [getClasses()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getClasses%28%29) method of your RestApplication class to return a Set containing your TestEndpoint class?

Comment: I did it now, but I got the same error, do you guys think it could be some problem with my dependencies? Should I explicit any other? Still did not get any console error

Comment: Guys, it worked, I'll edit my question to explain it, thanks

Comment: Can you please share the solution to your problem?

Comment: Hi @RoyiFreifeld I explained the solution in an edit, you can see it in the first line in the original post, it was just a misunderstanding about the context name

Comment: @VGR what does that override do?

Comment: @Ced As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getClasses--), returns a collection of all classes (other than the [singletons](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getSingletons--)) which provide REST resources.